# SSRS Report rotation

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have tried to search for solutions but found nothing, could be because there is a lot of issues with rotation of different report elements (text, images etc.), but this is not what I look for and I don't know how to re-phrase it better.

What I need to do is to switch between 2 reports back and forth, in i.e. 60 second intervals.

I'm not sure if this can be done, I would assume there is no custom properity which could point AutoRefresh to different report, but if it was possible to run action based on time past since *&ExecutionTime* it could be made.

At the moment I am considering a very dirty alternative of running the report in IFRAME with something like

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60;url=OtherReportURL">
```

but I'm almost sure there is a more elegant way to solve it.

EDIT: I found one similar thread on MSDN SSRS forum and it was suggested to use one report with subreports with visibility parameter depending on minute, i.e. visibility

```
=iif(Minute(now()) MOD 2 = 1 , True, False)
```

and the oposite for the other subreport, but I'm still looking for a prettier solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's a shame this feature isn't supported in SSRS, it seems like quite a common use case.

In the absence of direct support, something like this is probably the best we can do:

http://www.ticomix.com/blogs/crm/3-steps-to-creating-rotating-display-of-multiple-ssrs-reports

Answer (score 0):

The minute(now()) thing is actually a pretty good idea... Instead of using subreports, you could try to just play with the visibility of two tables.  How are you using the reports?  Or... what's calling them or are you talking about just a straight view from the report server?

Comment: I use regular web access to the report server. I need to put some reports on large screen displays and then just have them rotate between 2-3 pages. So far it works well with this visibility triggering but it would be still very useful if I could just refresh to another reports